# logins -axo command in linux oracle

Tags: linux, oracle

Anyone know what "logins -axo" means in linux os (for Oracle database)? and how to read the result?

i've got result below:

```
root:0:root:0:Super-User:/root:/sbin/sh:PS:092222:-1:28:21:-1:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Linux, but - the only [logins](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=l-logins-command) command I found is related to IBM's AIX.

Flags you used mean:

- **-a**: In addition to the default output, the -a flag adds two password expiration fields to the display. These fields show how many days a password can remain unused before it automatically becomes inactive and the date that the password will expire.
- **-o**: Formats output into one line of colon separated fields.
- **-x**: Prints an extended set of information about each selected user. Information for each user is printed on a separate line containing the home directory, login shell, and password aging information. The extended information includes the following:

  - The password status
  - The date on which the password was last changed
  - The number of days required between changes
  - The number of days allowed before a change is needed
  - The number of days that the user will receive a password expiration warning message before the password expires

  The password status is displayed in an abbreviated form as PS for logins with password, NP for no password or LK for locked.